# Trying to find error in JS code - Changing CSS with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am writing a simple function to toggle a menu for a mobile site but cannot get my code to work. I have looked at examples online and have followed them but I can't achieve to toggle the menu off.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMen(id) {    
     var a = document.getElementById(id);
    if(a.style.display='none'){
        a.style.display='block';
    }
    else if (a.style.display='block'){      
        a.style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I am trying to simply check what value display is at and set it accordingly. I know there may be more efficient ways but for now this is all I need.

Method Call:

`toggleMen('menu');`

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator is for **assigning** values.

The `===` (or `==` if you're feeling lucky) operator is for **comparing** values.

```
if (a.style.display === 'none') {
    a.style.display = 'block';
} else { 
    a.style.display = 'none';
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for more information on the difference between `===` and `==`.

BTW Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6cwedzq/).  After tinkering a bit, I realized your problem may have been that the original display wasn't set to anything (`a.display.style` was equal to `''`), so your conditional was never firing on either condition.  If that is the case, with the above changes, it will now fire the `else` on the first pass, and then alternate every pass after that.  (And if that isn't the case, the above changes should still do the trick)

Answer (score 0):

try `a.style.display == 'none'` instead of `a.style.display = 'none'`

Comment: I have tried before but I just tried again to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML:

```
<button onclick="toggleMen('menu');">Button</button>

<div id="menu">
    <div id="gripMenu">
    <div class="menuItem">Home</div>
    <div class="menuItem">Cake Builder</div>
    <div class="menuItem">Order</div>
    <div class="menuItem">Cakes</div>
    <div class="menuItem">Info</div>
    <div class="menuItem">About</div>
</div>
```

... And this JS:

```
function toggleMen(id){
    var a = document.getElementById(id);

    if(a.style.display === 'none'){
        a.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        a.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, although looks correct. This is a real head scratcher

Comment: Its not a wrong ID. It does change to block. I just cant change back to "none"

Comment: Remove ALL your css ... and test ... it works without your CSS!